# Stochastic Dominance Inequality

Tags: probability

Let $(X_i)_{1\le i\le n}$ and $(Y_i)_{1\le i\le n}$ be two sequences of random variables that only take non-negative integer values. Let $X=\sum_{1\le i\le n}X_i$ and $Y=\sum_{1\le i\le n}Y_i$.
If for all real numbers $t$ and $1\le i\le n$, we have
$$\mathbb{P}(X_i\le t)\le \mathbb{P}(Y_i\le t),$$
is it true that
$$\mathbb{P}(X\le t)\le \mathbb{P}(Y\le t)?$$

Comment: It would be easy to show if, by some miracle, $PX_i\ge Y_i)=1$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider $X_1=1-X_2$ with distribution
$$\mathbb P(X_1=0) = \mathbb P(X_1=1) = \frac12=\mathbb P(X_2=0) = \mathbb P(X_2=1)$$
and independent r.v.'s $Y_1, Y_2$  with distribution
$$\mathbb P(Y_1=0) = \mathbb P(Y_2=0) = \frac23, \quad \mathbb P(Y_1=1) = \mathbb P(Y_2=1)=\frac13.$$
Then for all real $t$
$$
\mathbb P(X_1 \leq t) \leq \mathbb P(Y_1 \leq t),
$$
$$
\mathbb P(X_2 \leq t) \leq \mathbb P(Y_2 \leq t)
$$
but $X_1+X_2=1$ and
$$
\mathbb P(Y_1+Y_2 = 2) =\frac19, 
$$
so
$$
\mathbb P(X_1+X_2 \leq 1.5) =1 > \mathbb P(Y_1+Y_2 \leq 1.5) = \frac89.
$$